# Javascript Regex to find all commas between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find all commas between two words and replace them with another string in JS.
I've tried literally every solution I've found but failed.

I have this HTML snippet (this is just a string looking like an html and not a
real html document)

```
<style>
a,span{color:#29728D;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover{ color:#69621C;text-decoration: underline;}
body, td{font-size:9pt; color:#333333}
</style>

<p>red, white, blue</p>
```

Now what I wanna do is replace those commas in the style tag with a random word such as "comma" or something.
But not replacing the commas in p or any other tags.

Closest I got was something like
`(?<=(le>\w)*),+(?=\w|\W(<\/style>))`

but did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1444609). Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. to be clear, he's not trying to parse html, only to use regex on the innerhtml of a tag

Comment: @jonatjano - Look at his regex pattern. He is trying to parse HTML.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. look at the question, he doesn't want to modify the tag, only the content

Comment: @jonatjano - Who said anything about trying to modify the tag? He is parsing HTML with regex! If he had a reference to the element in the DOM and wanted to modify it's innerHTML that would be one thing, but the guy is trying to parse an HTML document as a string with regex.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. maybe the problem is that he doesn't know how to select element, nor how to modify their contents

Comment: The html tag I have is in string form so I'm not trying to parse html.. it's just string looking like an html

Comment: you should have said that sooner, it change my answer

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. - wow, it's been years since I've seen Tony the Pony :p always makes me smile

Comment: What do you mean by "_it's just string looking like an html_". Your title mentions "_between two html tags_". Your string looks an awful lot like HTML. What part of it isn't?

Comment: sorry i edited by question. i should have mentioned that it's just a string

Comment: So, just because it's a string doesn't mean it's not parsable. Take a look at how Titus replaces the CSS selector for each rule.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No one is saying it's not parsable. It's just a bad idea ot try to do it with regex. You don't even need a DOM parser either. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I meant parsable in the sense of the built-in CSS rule parser; not text parsing. I am agreeing with you. Use an actual parser (API), not a regular expression. I was commenting on this from OP: _"it's just a string"_

Answer (score 1):

If you use DOM access you can change the content

```js
const snippet = `<style>
a,span{color:#29728D;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover{ color:#69621C;text-decoration: underline;}
body, td{font-size:9pt; color:#333333}
</style>

<p>red, white, blue</p>`

const domSnippet = document.createElement("x");
domSnippet.innerHTML=snippet;
const st = domSnippet.querySelector("style").textContent;
domSnippet.querySelector("style").textContent = st.replace(/,/g,"£££")
console.log(domSnippet.innerHTML);
```

```html
<style>
a,span{color:#29728D;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover{ color:#69621C;text-decoration: underline;}
body, td{font-size:9pt; color:#333333}
</style>

<p>red, white, blue</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to modify the css selectors in that string.
What you can do is parse the string as HTML, get the `<style>` element, modify its CSS rules (specifically the `selectorText`) and build a string from all the modified rules and set that as the new HTML content of the `<style>` element.

Here is an example:

```js
const content = `<style>
a,span{color:#29728D;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover{ color:#69621C;text-decoration: underline;}
body, td{font-size:9pt; color:#333333}
</style>

<p>red, white, blue</p>`

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, 'text/html');
const style = doc.querySelector('style');

const result = [...style.sheet.cssRules]
  .reduce((acc, rule) => {
    rule.selectorText = rule.selectorText.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ' comma ');
    acc += rule.cssText +'\n';
    return acc;
  }, '\n');


style.innerHTML = result;
const newContent = doc.head.innerHTML + '\n' + doc.body.innerHTML;

console.log(newContent);
```

Comment: Alright, this is the answer. **Note:** I would probably gobble the spaces surrounding the comma too: `/\s*,\s*/g`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I've added that but I don't think it is necessary because the `CSSStyleSheet` seems to format the `cssText` string to remove any extra unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I get it, when you change the `selectorText`, the resulting `cssText` will auto-format anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses pure string functions. No regex, no DOM parsing. This method will be more robust than using `DOMParser()` because it can safely handle broken HTML without errors and it will work outside of a browser if you need it to.

```js
const document_body = `<style>
a,span{color:#29728D;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover{ color:#69621C;text-decoration: underline;}
body, td{font-size:9pt; color:#333333}
</style>

<p>red, white, blue</p>`;


var parsed, modified = document_body, current_index = -1;
while ((parsed = getTagContent(modified, '<style>', '</style>', current_index)) !== false) {
  let tag_contents = modified.substring(parsed.start, parsed.end);
  let modified_tag_contents = tag_contents.replace(/,/g, 'COMMA');
  modified = modified.substring(0, parsed.start) + modified_tag_contents + modified.substring(parsed.end);
  current_index = parsed.end - (modified_tag_contents.length - tag_contents.length);
}

console.log("Original: "+document_body);
console.log("Modifided: "+modified);

function getTagContent(html_body, start_tag, end_tag, start_index = 0) {
  var start = html_body.indexOf(start_tag, start_index);
  if (start === -1) return false;
  var end = html_body.indexOf(end_tag, start);
  if (end === -1) return false;
  return {
    start: start + start_tag.length,
    end
  };
}
```